# Pattern matching an array with specific start and end words/characters

Tags: perl

Have some output in an array which I am trying to pull details from where the output begins with a specific word and ends with a specific word/character.  This output is then to be printed to the screen.

The output in the array which I am working with is:

```
router rip
 version 2
 redistribute bgp 45134 metric 3
 passive-interface Serial1/3:1.333
 passive-interface Serial3/1:3.333
 passive-interface Serial3/1:5.333
 passive-interface Serial3/2:1.333
 passive-interface Serial3/4:1.333
 passive-interface Serial3/4:17.333
 passive-interface Serial6/1:1.333
 no auto-summary
 !
 address-family ipv4 vrf TestVRF-0001
 redistribute bgp 45134 metric 3
 network 10.0.0.0
 no auto-summary
 version 2
 exit-address-family
 !
```

The perl code I have generated so far is below:

```
    elsif ( $action eq "show_vrf1" ) {
            my $cmd = "show run | begin router rip";
            my @lines = $s->cmd(String => $cmd,
                            Prompt  => "/$enableprompt/",
                            Timeout => 10);
            foreach my $line (@lines) {
                if(/address-family ipv4 vrf TestVRF-0001.*?!/){
                $result=$1;
                print $result;
                }
            }
    }
```

Which I am wanting to only pull the below out of the array:

```
 address-family ipv4 vrf TestVRF-0001
 redistribute bgp 45134 metric 3
 network 10.0.0.0
 no auto-summary
 version 2
 exit-address-family
 !
```

For some reason when I run the script, I just get a blank screen with no data pulled from the array.

Comment: what is output of `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@lines;`?

Comment: Perhaps you should give some clue as to what kind of object `$s` is. And perhaps you should state why you seem to be using a module to perform a backtick/qx command.

Comment: Sorry $s is used to open a session to the Cisco device so that the commands can be initiated.  In terms of using the module to perform backtick/qx, this is how the script was initially put together before a fellow employee left without any handover.

Comment: `Dumper \@lines`. It's great debugging tool.

Comment: Thanks guys, got it going with 'choroba' config and the print Dumper \@lines command...if I could buy you guys a drink I would!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You match $line against the regular expression. The output you expect is not on one line, so no line can match it.

You can store the whole multiline string in a scalar:

```
my $output = join q(), $s->cmd(...);
```

And then, you can retrieve the output, if you use parentheses to really capture a part of the string:

```
if ($output =~ /(address-family ipv4 vrf TestVRF-0001.*?!)/s) {
    my $result = $1;
```

Note that the `/s` modifier is needed to make dot match a newline, which it normaly does not.

Comment: You can only store it in a scalar if the module has that functionality, and we do not know what kind of object `$s` is.

Comment: Can't answer my own questions yet, but will put as much as I can here, $s = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 10, Prompt => "/$prompt/",
Dump_Log => "$filename"

Comment: Thanks 'choroba', your code worked perfectly...and now makes sense using the scalar to store the entire multiline output and to then capture part of the string as directed. Thanks Heaps !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
                if($line =~ /address-family ipv4 vrf TestVRF-0001.*?!/){
```

instead of

```
                if(/address-family ipv4 vrf TestVRF-0001.*?!/){
```

?